# Defining two objects of differeent classes inside each class

Tags: java, swing

I created two classes.

One class is called `Frames`, and inside it I defined a `Jframe` and an `Image`.

In another class which is called `Panels`, I defined a `Jpanel`.

I want to pass the panel to Frames class  using getPanel method and pass the image to the Panels class using getImage methods.

So I created a Frames object inside Panels class to call getImage
and created a Panels object inside Frames class to call getPanel.
But when I run the code, this message appears:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError.

```
public class panels{

    frames framesObject = new frames();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
        public void painComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(frames.getImage(),0,0,null);
        }
    };

    public Jpanel getPanel(){
        return panel;
    }

}

public class frames{

    JFrame frame= new JFrame();
    Toolkit toolkit= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image image = toolkit.getImage("..source file..");
    panels panelsObject= new panels();
    frame.add(panelsObject.getPanel());

    public Image getImage(){
        return image;
}
```

Comment: Maybe, have a `setImage` method in your `Panels` class and pass the image from the `Frame` class to it ... it's all kind of convoluted if you ask me

Comment: Seems like the error is generated by both of them calling each other until you run out of memory - hard to help without any code provided though.

Answer (score 0):

> So I created a `Frames` object inside `Panels` class to call `getImage()` and created a `Panels` object inside `Frames` class to call `getPanel()`.

So you created a mutual recursion.

Solution: don't. Make up your mind about which should be inside which, and stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you're building an endless recursion, which leads to a stackoverflow...

I think the simplest way to get this to work would be to instantiate `class 2` in `class 1` and then pass the object of `class 1` to `class 2`. Doing so, you have a reference to each other in both of them.

```
public class panels{

    public JPanel panel;

    public panels(frames framesObject){
        panel = new JPanel(){
            public void painComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(framesObject.getImage(),0,0,null);
            }
        };
    }

    public Jpanel getPanel(){
        return panel;
    }

}

public class frames{

    public Image image;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new frames();
    }

    public frames(){
        JFrame frame= new JFrame();
        Toolkit toolkit= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        image = toolkit.getImage("..source file..");
        panels panelsObject= new panels(this);
        frame.add(panelsObject.getPanel());
    }

    public Image getImage(){
        return image;
    }
}
```